# Easy network monitoring for outbound packet dropping

Tags: networking, ping

I am having some issues with my home network, and they all seem to be related to Comcast sucking.  I want some way to monitor my outbound traffic - ping command is fine.  I would like something that keeps the details and generates fancy statistics.

I know I can script something, but my request is more along the lines of something that already exists, or if someone has already written the scripts that I can use.

I have a mikrotik router and didn't find much help there.  I also have a QNAP file server running linux.

Any suggestions you have are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org) monitors your network and generates extensive logs for later analysis. It also captures ICMP traffic, as you mention in the question. After installing it, just give it an interface to sniff on:

```
bro -i en0
```

and Bro starts generating logs in the same directory you started. There exists also an interactive shell to configure and run Bro, called [BroControl](http://www.bro-ids.org/documentation/components/broctl/README.html).